# Passing values from Blazor layout to Page

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to pass values from a select control on a blazor layout as they change to the current page. i.e. I have a dropdown that when the values is changed it needs to tell the page (via an event, parameter or cascasding parameter I'm not sure):

So far I have this:

## _layout.razor

```
<div class="page">
     <select onchange="OnSiteChanged">
         <option value="1">Site 1</option>
         <option value="2">Site 2</option>
     </select>
</div>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public EventHandler SiteChanged{ get; set; }

     private void OnSiteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         SiteChanged.Invoke(this, e);
     }
}
```

and pass it to the underlying page:

## pagewithlayout.razor

```
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback SiteChanged { get; set; }

     public async Task OnSiteChanged(EventArgs e){
         /do something
     }
}
```

However the event on the page never fires. Any ideas?

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900179/calling-the-method-in-body-from-mainlayout-blazor?

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually trying to do.  I don't want to hurt your progress by telling you the right way to do the wrong thing.  Why do you have a dropdown in your layout page, and what actually are Site 1 and Site 2?  Could you please explain the real-life goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @Bennyboy1973. Your patience is appreciated. I want a dropdown on every page so I've put it in the layout. The dropdown contains a list of clients sites (physical locations) and as the user changes the site each page will show data/functionality for that site. For example, we have many reports that are site specific.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yes something like that although it seems rather complicated for something that would be trivial in something like javascript on the client side.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.layoutcomponentbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0 "Alternatively, components may implement IComponent directly and declare their own parameter named Body." So what if all your page components `@inherits` a common base type, matching the layout `Body` property type... ? (I haven't worked with blazor at all though, so I don't know if that idea would work).

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLakeman you other post works for me with a few alterations.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @JeremyLakeman for the help that lead to this answer. This answer is specific to layouts publishing data to their pages.

## Notification Service

First, I had to create a service to encapsulate the event:

```
public class NotifiySiteChangedService
{
    public EventHandler? SiteChanged;

    public void OnSiteChanged(object sender, SiteIdChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SiteChanged != null)
        {
            this.SiteChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class SiteIdChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    public SiteIdChangeEventArgs(int siteId) : base()
    {
        SiteId = siteId;
    }
}
```

## Program.cs

Then to make it available in the app I had to register it in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<NotifiySiteChangedService>();
```

## MainLayout.razor

Then in the layout:

```
<select onchange="@SiteIdChanged">
    <option value="1">Site 1</option>
    <option value="2">Site 2</option>
</select>

@code{
    [Inject] private NotifiySiteChangedService? service { get; set; }
    private NotifiySiteChangedService Service => service!;

    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    void SiteIdChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            SiteId = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
            Service.OnSiteChanged(this, new SiteIdChangeEventArgs(SiteId));
        }
    }
}
```

## Index.razor

```
@code {
    [Inject] private NotifiySiteChangedService? service { get; set; }
    private NotifiySiteChangedService Service => service!;

    public int SiteId{get;set;}
    void SiteIdChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SiteId = ((SiteIdChangeEventArgs)e).SiteId;
    } 

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.Service.SiteChanged += this.SiteIdChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Comment: You got it.  Commonly known as a Notification Service.

Comment: Thanks @MrCakaShaunCurtis I've updated the answer with the usual name.

Comment: [Politely put] @MrCakaShaunCurtis,  Sorry, the service created here is definitley not `Commonly known as a Notification Service.` A `Notification Service` is something different altogether. I, at least, defined it as follows: `You may define a class service that implements the `State pattern` and the `Notifier pattern` to handle the state of your objects, pass state to objects, and notify subscriber objects of changes.` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042629/6152891 Incidentally, Guy Lowe, I believe that it is more appropriate to use cascading parameter rather than a service in this case.

Comment: Thanks @enet I trie d cascading parameters but couldn't get it to work. I'm potentially over engineering it in this case I guess.

Comment: @GuyLowe, I've added a second answer to demonstarte how to do that...